# Is it ok geth need any delay untill it start to listen RPC-port?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

My app launches Geth process like this: `geth --cache=512 --rpc`
Next it immediately starts to process incoming requests and sends some needed data to http://localhost:8545 (i.e. to geth for the interaction by RPC protocol). 
However at the first time after launch (about 5 seconds) geth returns:

> Failed to connect to localhost port 8545: Connection refused

Afterwards it works great.

Is such behavior standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is normal, rpc server needs some time to run and sometimes it could fail then you should start it within the cli.